# Cannot upload file in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I'm trying to upload file using PHP. I can do it in the "local server", however it does not work in the "remote server" [Output at the bottom of this post].

**Frontend**

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('debug.testupload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="photo">
      <input type="submit" class="btn mt-10 mt-sml-20" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Backend**

```php
public function testProcessSubmit(Request $request){

echo (sys_get_temp_dir());
dd($_FILES);
return "0";
}
```

**Output (Local Server)**

[image: Output (Local Server)]]

**Output (Remote Server)**

[image: Output (Remote Server]

- This is the php configuration in my server:

  - file_uploads: On
  - upload_max_filesize: 2M
  - max_file_uploads: 20

**Edit**
Permission
/tmp: 777

Comment: What is file permissions on a remote server?

Comment: permission for /tmp is 777

Comment: where is `request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);` ?

Comment: _"upload_max_filesize: 2M"_ - Looking at the screen shot from your local server, the file (since you seem to be posting the same file) seems to be 4MB, which is twice the max size.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (And chances are you would have seen the culprit, if your ini settings were listed next to the error/size dump from the prior tests).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes you're right, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

"upload_max_filesize: 2M" - Looking at the screenshot from your local server, the file (since you seem to be posting the same file) seems to be 4MB,

which is twice the max size.